# Is it possible to pass an implicit function as a function pointer in C?

Tags: c, function-pointers

Recently I found out that it is possible to pass an implicit array to a function by casting it in the function call

```
void foo(int* array);
foo((int[4]) {1,2,3,4});
```

However, I was wondering if it was possible to do the same thing when passing a function pointer to a function, so something like:

```
void bar(void (*foobar)(void));
bar((void) {printf("foobar\n");});
```

So Is it even possible to do this?

The reason I want to know is that if I have a large block of code which may have a certain loop structure, but the core functionality changes between instances, I don't want to have to litter my code with multiple temporary functions just to pass them to another function. Hence wanting to be able to define the temporary function in the parameters.

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, not in standard C. You have two non-standard alternatives, though:

One. GCC's "nested functions" extension (GCC only):

```
void call(void (*fn)())
{
    fn();
}

void somefunc()
{
    void tmp_func()
    {
        printf("Hello world!\n");
    }
    call(tmp_func);
}
```

Two, Apple's blocks (recent GCC and Clang):

```
void call(void (^blk)())
{
    blk();
}

call(^{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
});
```

Comment: As an aside to the first method, there's also the some macros (and explanations) in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405436/anonymous-functions-using-gcc-statement-expressions - not to mention the slightly more nuts version here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#C_lambda_expressions

Comment: @slugonamission Let's not hack with the preprocessor :)

Comment: fair enough :) - I just found them interesting when poking around for this answer. I tend to take the line that if you don't understand the macro, you probably shouldn't have it in your code though :)

Comment: @slugonamission [I have written an ugly hack](https://github.com/H2CO3/libblock) to make old GCC versions "support" blocks, and I hate it.

Comment: ouch. That's quite something

Answer (score 1):

The "implicit array" is actually a [compound literal](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Compound-Literals.html) and it's C99 specific.

Anonymous functions on the other hand can't be achieved using standard C. If you use GNU GCC, you could mimic them using two extensions:

1. [Nested Functions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html)
2. [Statement expressions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html)

First create a wrapper macro:

```
#define lambda(return_type, body)     \
({                                    \
    return_type lambda_function body; \
    lambda_function;                  \
})
```

Then you can use it like this

```
bar(lambda(void, (void)
    {
        printf("foobar\n");
    })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you're looking for is not part of the C standard. However, this is exactly the problem (or one of the problems) that **blocks** — an Apple extension to the standard — were designed to fix. If you're compiling for OS X 10.5 or later (or using `clang` with a Blocks runtime on other supported platforms; see [mackyle/blocksruntime](https://github.com/mackyle/blocksruntime)), you can change your code to something like this:

```
void bar(void (^foobar)(void));
```

And invoke like this:

```
bar(^{
    printf("foobar\n");
});
```