# Is it possible to write a function which returns a pointer to a function different from the function in its argument?

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-pointers

I have recently stumbled on this curious thought while handling a C code.
I have written a function which returns a double and takes in as argument the pointer to a function and a certain number of parameters, namely

```
double template_1(double (*)(double),...);
```

this function correctly identifies a certain property of a real function

```
 double f(double );
```

represented as a pointer in `template_1`, in order to make`template_1` valid for every real function I might plug-in.

Now I had to write another function, let it be:

```
double derivative(double (*)(double),double);

double derivative(double (*f)(double),double x){

    double epsilon = ...; 

    return ( f(x+epsilon)-f(x-epsilon) )/(2.0*epsilon);
}
```

again with f in the argument to make it work for every f.
My question is: since I would like to use `derivative` in `template_1` without modifying it, is it possible to write a function which takes derivative and spits out something that has the form  of `double (*)(double )` ?

My idea was to define  `typedef double (*real_function)(double);`
and then to define

```
real_function g(double (*derivative)(double (*)(double),double ) )
```

which  I'd like it to spit out something like: `double derivative_2(double x)`; so that I could define something like `g(derivative) = double (*h)( double);` directly in `template_1 argument`
unfortunately I don't have the faintest idea of how to make this work, or even if it can work.

Comment: It would be possible only in case this returned function is defined already. No, you can't "define" functions in the runtime. You will have to switch to some functional language such as Haskell or Lisp for this.

Comment: There's no (portable) way to create a function at runtime in C.

Comment: @EugeneSh. most languages, and not just functional ones, support this (at least in some form) -- for example C++, java, go.

Comment: @PaulHankin Wasn't sure about that. I am familiar with functional ones more :) Higher order functions and currying is just very natural there.

Comment: Post needs title re-statement.  "is it possible to write a function which returns a pointer to a function different from the function in its argument?" Sure, `real_function foo(real_function rf, ...) { return exp; }` is a positive answer to the question, but likely not what OP wants per the body of the post.

Comment: You are basically asking for some sort of stateful function, which you can realize in C by adding an opaque context parameter to each of your functions and which you use to store the state in.

Comment: I'm not sure I did understand, could you please expand on what you mean or  point to some reference? thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning: I am a C++ developer with little C knowledge so everything that follows is likely unidiomatic C.

As [KerrekSB said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43054787/is-it-possible-to-write-a-function-which-returns-a-pointer-to-a-function-differe#comment73195031_43054787), you would need to carry some state with your function. This is not possible with raw functions but you can define a struct that carries the state and add a function that works with this struct. This obviously has the drawback of losing the nice function call syntax. I whipped up an example:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef double (*raw_fptr)(double);
struct real_function;
typedef double (*evaluate_function)(struct real_function*, double);

struct real_function {
        evaluate_function evaluate;
};
typedef struct real_function real_function;

double evaluate(real_function *f, double x) {
        if(f) {
                return f->evaluate(f, x);
        }
        return NAN;
}

struct raw_real_function {
        real_function real_function_base;
        raw_fptr raw_function;
};
typedef struct raw_real_function raw_real_function;

double evaluate_raw_real_function(real_function *f_base, double x) {
        if(f_base) {
                raw_real_function *f = (raw_real_function*)f_base;
                return f->raw_function(x);
        }
        return NAN;
}

raw_real_function make_raw_real_function(raw_fptr function) {
        raw_real_function result;
        result.raw_function = function;
        result.real_function_base.evaluate = evaluate_raw_real_function;
        return result;
}

struct derive_real_function {
        real_function real_function_base;
        real_function *function_to_derive;
};
typedef struct derive_real_function derive_real_function;

double derive(real_function *f_base, double x) {
        derive_real_function *f = (derive_real_function*)f_base;
        double epsilon = 1e-3;
        double upper = evaluate(f->function_to_derive, x+epsilon);
        double lower = evaluate(f->function_to_derive, x-epsilon);
        double result =  (upper - lower)/(2.0*epsilon);
        return result;
}

derive_real_function make_derivative(real_function * function_to_derive) {
        derive_real_function result;
        result.real_function_base.evaluate = derive;
        result.function_to_derive = function_to_derive;
        return result;
}

double x_cubed(double x) {
        return x * x * x;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        raw_real_function x_cubed_wrapped = make_raw_real_function(x_cubed);
        derive_real_function derived = make_derivative(&x_cubed_wrapped.real_function_base);
        derive_real_function derived_twice = make_derivative(&derived.real_function_base);
        double x = atof(argv[1]);
        double derivative = evaluate(&derived.real_function_base, x);
        double second_derivative = evaluate(&derived_twice.real_function_base, x);
        printf("derivative of x^3 at %f = %f\n", x, derivative);
        printf("second derivative of x^3 at %f = %f\n", x, second_derivative);
        return 0;
}
```

See (a slight variaton, due to input limitations) running [here](http://ideone.com/lBB5CG).

How does it work? I faked some inheritance with the structs `real_function`, `raw_real_function` and `derive_real_function` to generate virtual function calls. The `struct real_function` serves as the container of a virtual function table consisting of only the entry `evaluate`. This function pointer points to the "derived" structs' relevant evaluate function:

`raw_real_function` instances point to `evaluate_raw_real_function` (as initialized in `make_raw_real_function`. `derive_real_function` instances point `evaluate` to `derive` (as initialized in `make_derivative`).

When calling `evaluate` on the `real_function_base` member, it will call the associated evaluation function, which casts the `real_function*` to it's associated struct pointer and does what is needed with that information.

Since everything is just a `real_function*`, we can chain them at will but need to convert "normal" functions into the `real_function` format, that's what `make_raw_real_function` does.

Comment: It took me quite a while to understand the answer, thank you very much. I guess the main lesson here is that I'll learn more about C++

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple ways to do anonymous functions in C. As the comments said, they aren't portable. But depending on the use case you may find this useful: [Anonymous functions using GCC statement expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405436/anonymous-functions-using-gcc-statement-expressions)

A couple of people have seemed to have similar issues, not sure how portable they are but they may be resourceful:
https://github.com/graphitemaster/lambdapp
https://github.com/Leushenko/C99-Lambda

Basically, if there's a way to architect your program in a way that doesn't require anonymous functions, then do it that way. If you have no other option, then I would give one of these a shot.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a function `my_fancy_function`:

```
double my_fancy_function (double x) { return sin(x) + cos(x); }
```

Then, you can use a helper macro that creates the derived function for you.

```
#define DEFINE_DERIVATIVE_OF(FUNC) \
double derivative_of_ ## FUNC (double x) { \
    return derivative(FUNC, x); \
}

DEFINE_DERIVATIVE_OF(my_fancy_function)
```

You then pass this newly defined function to your template.

```
template_1(derivative_of_my_fancy_function, x, y, z);
```

Comment: that is an awesome solution, yet not exactly what I was looking for.