# Are anonymous functions supported in C?

Tags: c, programming-languages, anonymous-function

I’m curious if anonymous functions are possible and acceptable (by which I mean, possible, but not necessarily “good”) in C. I haven’t heard of it before, but I don’t want to look silly disagreeing with someone who might say it is (but won’t produce an example).

[In this other SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405436/anonymous-functions-using-gcc-statement-expressions), it seems like it’s possible in a specific case of GNU C, but doesn’t address it more generally.

Comment: It's not possible in pure standard C. And if you intend to ask me to prove a negative, I present to you [n1570](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html). The last draft before publication of C11. You'll find there is no provision for it.

Comment: The linked answer explains how the effect is achieved using GNU extensions. There is no standard way to do it.

Comment: @StoryTeller If I understand you correctly, you want some clarity over whether I'm asking to prove a negative. I.E., prove it's NOT possible to have anonymous functions in C. I'm actually asking if it IS possible, however, I don't think it is based on my informal exposure to C and general assumptions derived from practice. Thanks for the like to the standard BTW :)